# Jquery Fade In Fade Out Issue in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, fadein, fadeout

I have created this simple image slider using jQuery:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UcQE6/5/)

I found that it runs perfectly in all the other browsers except for Safari in which it lags quite a bit.

Here's my code snippet of my script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    loadLandingSlider();
});
var counter = 0;

function loadLandingSlider() {
    totalImg = $('#rotating-item-wrapper img').length;

    rotate = setInterval(function () {
        loadImg();
    }, 3000);
}

function loadImg() {
    $('.rotating-item').fadeOut(1000);
    $('#rot' + counter).fadeIn(1000);

    if (counter == totalImg)
        counter = 1;
    else 
        counter++;
}
```

Is there some workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi It doesn't lag in Safari (6.0.5) on OSX but your pictures are ways to big. 7 x 500kB is a lot of stuff to load and handle. Maybe this causes your lags.

Comment: I have scaled down the number of images exactly for that reason. They are all 72dpi, so I'm not sure how to lessen the load. I have scaled the currently used images to the correct sizes.

Comment: A workaround might be to use only two images and change the source, but I'll have to test it first

Comment: Use a programm with a better png compression or upload your pictures to tinypng.com. A test with one of your pictures reduced the size of your png's about 50%. But why aren't you using jpg instead? Your picture will be less then one-tenth without visible quality loss.

Comment: i can't use  jpg's, because of the shape of the images. There's a frame effect

Comment: It seems that the image sizes was the main issue. Thanks